# $\int \phi \chi_{_{[0,1/n]}}dx\to \phi(0)$ for $\phi\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\phi\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ which is the space of functions that vanish at infinity (the completion of $C_c(\mathbb{R})$. I would like to show that $\int \phi\cdot n\chi_{_{[0,1/n]}}dx\to \phi(0)$. This seems intuitive since we put more and more weight on the point $x=0$ but I don't know where to start to show it properly. Also,it doesn't really seem important that $\phi$ is vanishing at infinity, is it?

Comment: it doesn't matter what happens near $\infty$, but your equation is missing a factor of $n$ as in $\int_\mathbb{R}\phi\cdot n\chi_{[0,1/n]}\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^1\to\phi(0)$.

Comment: Thank you, I added it

Comment: Hint: Use that $a:=\phi(0)=\int a n \chi_{[0,1/n]} d x$ together with the fact that $\vert \phi(x) - a \vert$ is small for $0\le x \le 1/n$ by continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous at $0$ there exists some $\delta >0$ such that, for all $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$ you have
$$
|\varphi(x)- \varphi(0) | <\epsilon \,.
$$

Now, for all $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$ you have
$$
\left|\int_\mathbb{R}\phi(x)\cdot n\chi_{[0,1/n]}\,\mathrm{d}(x) -\varphi(0) \right|=\left|\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}(\phi(x)\cdot n -\varphi(0) \cdot n)\mathrm{d}(x)\right| \leq
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\left| \phi(x)\cdot n -\varphi(0) \cdot n\right|\mathrm{d}(x)
$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it